# regularity theorem for lebesgue measure

Tags: lebesgue-measure

I'm having trouble with this problem. I was able to show that if a set A is measurable then for every $\epsilon$ $>$ $0$, there
exists both an open set $G$ and a closed set $F$ such that $F$ $⊂$ $A$ $⊂$ $G$ and
$m($G\F) $<$ $\epsilon$.

But I can't figure out how to do it in the other direction. Any advice?

Comment: In other words, if such $F$ and $G$ exist, then $A$ is measurable?

Comment: Use that open and closed sets are measurable and that null-sets are measurable, and finally that countable unions/intersections of measurable sets are measurable.